# Create trigger ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have to create a trigger that records order numbers in the purchase table. PURCHASE the training database and audit information into the AUDIT_TAB table. This is a task from the book Christopher Allen How to write powerful and flexible programs on PL / SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE    audit
(ORDER_NUMBER   NUMBER(10),
person_code         VARCHAR2(3),
user_name       CHAR(30),
user_machine        CHAR(20),
change_in_quant     NUMBER(5),
transaction_time    DATE,
FOREIGN KEY (person_code) REFERENCES persoon);

CREATE SEQUENCE order_num_seq;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  audit_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON purchase
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
no_name_change EXCEPTION;
quant_change        NUMBER(5) := 0;
BEGIN

IF (UPDATING
AND
(:NEW.product_name <> :OLD.product_name))
THEN
RAISE no_name_change;
END IF;

IF (((UPDATING)
AND
(:OLD.ORDER_NUMBER  IS  NULL))
OR
((INSERTING)
AND
(:NEW.ORDER_NUMBER  IS  NULL)))
THEN
SELECT order_num_seq.NEXTVAL
INTO    :NEW.ORDER_NUMBER
FROM    dual;
END IF;


IF (UPDATING)
THEN
quant_change := :NEW. quantity - :OLD. quantity;
ELSE
quant_change := :NEW. quantity;
END IF;
INSERT INTO audit
VALUES ( :NEW.ORDER_NUMBER,
    :NEW.salesperson,
    USER,
    USERENV ( 'TERMINAL' ) ,
    quant_change,
    SYSDATE) ;
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_name_change
THEN
dbms_output.put_line ('Change of product name not allowed');
dbms_output.put_line ('Aborting and resetting to old values');
:NEW.product_name       := :OLD.product_name;
:NEW. salesperson       := :OLD.salesperson;
:NEW.ORDER_NUMBER   := :OLD.ORDER_NUMBER;
:NEW. quantity          := :OLD.quantity;
END audit_trigger ;
/
```

And trigger compiled with warnings. Why? What's my mistake?

My database:

```
CREATE TABLE person (    
person_code VARCHAR2(3) PRIMARY KEY,    
first_name VARCHAR2(15),    
last_name VARCHAR2(20),    
hire_date DATE    
);
CREATE INDEX person_name_index    
ON person(last_name, first_name);    
ALTER TABLE person    
ADD CONSTRAINT person_unique UNIQUE (    
first_name,    
last_name,    
hire_date    
);    
INSERT INTO person VALUES    
('CA', 'Charlene', 'Atlas', '01-ФЕВ-02');
INSERT INTO person VALUES    
('GA', 'Gary', 'Andersen', '15-ФЕВ-02' );
INSERT INTO person VALUES    
('BB', 'Bobby', 'Barkenhagen', '28-ФЕВ-02');    
INSERT INTO person VALUES    
('LB', 'Laren', 'Baxter', '01-МАР-02 ');    
INSERT INTO person VALUES    
('LN', 'Linda', 'Norton', '01-ИЮН-03'); 

CREATE TABLE product (
product_name VARCHAR2(25) PRIMARY KEY,
product_price NUMBER(4,2),
quantity_on_hand NUMBER(5,0),
last_stock_date DATE
);
ALTER TABLE product ADD (
CONSTRAINT positive_quantity CHECK(
quantity_on_hand IS NOT NULL
AND
quantity_on_hand >= 0)
);
INSERT INTO product VALUES 
('Small Widget', 99, 1, '15-ЯНВ-03' );
INSERT INTO product VALUES
( 'Medium Wodget', 75, 1000, '15-ЯНВ-02' );
INSERT INTO product VALUES
('Chrome Phoobar', 50, 100, '15-ЯНВ-03' );
INSERT INTO product VALUES
('Round Chrome Snaphoo', 25, 10000, null);
INSERT INTO product VALUES
('Extra Huge Mega Phoobar +', 9.95, 1234, '15-ЯНВ-04' );
INSERT INTO product VALUES ('Square Zinculator',
45, 1, TO_DATE ('Декабрь 31, 2002, 11:30',
'Month dd, YYYY, HH:MI'));
INSERT INTO product VALUES (
'Anodized Framifier', 49, 5, NULL);
INSERT INTO product VALUES (
'Red Snaphoo', 1.95, 10, '31-ДЕК-01');
INSERT INTO product VALUES (
'Blue Snaphoo', 1.95, 10, '30-ДЕК-01'); 

CREATE TABLE purchase (
product_name VARCHAR2(25),
salesperson VARCHAR2(3),
purchase_date DATE,
quantity NUMBER(4,2)
);
ALTER TABLE purchase
ADD PRIMARY KEY (product_name,
salesperson,
purchase_date
);
ALTER TABLE purchase ADD (
CONSTRAINT reasonable_date CHECK(
purchase_date IS NOT NULL
AND
TO_CHAR(purchase_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2000-06-30')
);
ALTER TABLE purchase
ADD CONSTRAINT purchase_fk_product FOREIGN KEY
(product_name) REFERENCES product;
ALTER TABLE purchase
ADD CONSTRAINT purchase_fk_person FOREIGN KEY
(salesperson) REFERENCES person;
CREATE INDEX purchase_product
ON purchase(product_name);
CREATE INDEX purchase_salesperson
on purchase(salesperson);
INSERT INTO purchase VALUES
('Small Widget', 'CA', '14-ИЮЛ-03', 1);
INSERT INTO purchase VALUES
('Medium Wodget', 'BB', '14-ИЮЛ-03', 75);
INSERT INTO purchase VALUES
('Chrome Phoobar', 'GA', '14-ИЮЛ-03', 2);
INSERT INTO purchase VALUES
('Small Widget', 'GA', '15-ИЮЛ-03', 8);
INSERT INTO purchase VALUES
('Medium Wodget', 'LB', '15-ИЮЛ-03', 20);
INSERT INTO purchase VALUES
('Round Chrome Snaphoo', 'CA', '16-ИЮЛ-03', 5);
INSERT INTO purchase VALUES
('Small Widget', 'CA', '17-ИЮЛ-03', 1); 
CREATE TABLE purchase_archive (
product_name VARCHAR2 (25),
salesperson VARCHAR2(3),
purchase_date DATE,
quantity NUMBER (4, 2)
);
INSERT INTO purchase_archive VALUES
('Round Snaphoo', 'BB', '21-ИЮН-01', 10);
INSERT INTO purchase_archive VALUES
('Large Harflinger ' , 'GA', '22-ИЮН-01', 50);
INSERT INTO purchase_archive VALUES
('Medium Wodget', 'LB', '23-ИЮН-01', 20);
INSERT INTO purchase_archive VALUES
('Small Widget', 'ZZ', '24-ИЮН-02', 80);
INSERT INTO purchase_archive VALUES
('Chrome Phoobar', 'CA', '25-ИЮН-02', 2);
INSERT INTO purchase_archive VALUES
('Small Widget', 'JT', '26-ИЮН-02', 50);
```

Comment: What compilation errors?

Comment: @APC [link](https://yadi.sk/i/gs9fGRYK3JfQZN) only warnings

Comment: Compilation warnings are errors. Please post them here **as text**. I'm not downloading some dodgy image from an unknown site

Comment: [2]: (Warning) PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.'
[2]: (Warning) PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.'
[2]: (Warning) PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "QUANTITY" when expecting one of the following:     . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like LIKE2_    LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between || indicator multiset member    SUBMULTISET_

Answer (score 3):

There are few errors i can see.

1) Your `Purchase` table is not having  `ORDER_NUMBER` column which you are trying to use in your code. Add that column and yoour code should work then.

2) Definition of `Audit` table is not correct. Its referencing a table which doesnot exist. `persoon` table doesnot exist. Also `AUDIT` is a reserve keyword, so it should not be used.

You can check those and compile again.

Error you are getting because of spaces between `:OLD. quantity` . See the working version of code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_trigger
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON PURCHASE
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   no_name_change   EXCEPTION;
   quant_change     NUMBER (5) := 0;
BEGIN
   IF (UPDATING AND (:NEW.product_name <> :OLD.product_name))
   THEN
      RAISE no_name_change;
   END IF;

   IF (   ( (UPDATING) AND (:OLD.ORDER_NUMBER IS NULL))
       OR ( (INSERTING) AND (:NEW.ORDER_NUMBER IS NULL)))
   THEN
      SELECT order_num_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ORDER_NUMBER FROM DUAL;
   END IF;


   IF (UPDATING)
   THEN
      quant_change := :NEW.quantity - :OLD.quantity;
   ELSE
      quant_change := :NEW.quantity;
   END IF;

   INSERT INTO audit1
        VALUES (:NEW.ORDER_NUMBER,
                :NEW.salesperson,
                USER,
                USERENV ('TERMINAL'),
                quant_change,
                SYSDATE);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN no_name_change
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Change of product name not allowed');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Aborting and resetting to old values');
      :NEW.product_name := :OLD.product_name;
      :NEW.salesperson := :OLD.salesperson;
      :NEW.ORDER_NUMBER := :OLD.ORDER_NUMBER;
      :NEW.quantity := :OLD.quantity;
END audit_trigger;
/
```

Comment: Sorry, in this code I wrote persoon. But in my real code - I wrote `person`.  Thank you, I'll try.

Comment: Please change according to both of my suggestions and your code should compile. Also if that fix your problem, close the question by acceptiing the solution,\

Comment: Okey, I'll try! Thanks for the answer

Comment: I changed according to both your suggestions and code compiled. And I've got warnings

[2]: (Warning) PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.'
[2]: (Warning) PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.'
[2]: (Warning) PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "QUANTITY" when expecting one of the following:     . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like LIKE2_    LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between || indicator multiset member    SUBMULTISET_

Comment: @z_u_l - you need to develop a cool eye when looking at your own programs. You cannot expect strangers on the internet to devote their time to scrawling through vast swathes of code trying to spot bugs. The problem XING pointed out, the space `:NEW. `/`':OLD.` and the referenced column, occurred in several places for  `QUANTITY` and `SALESPERSON`. Having been given the first clue you could have fixed the others yourself.